# I can't use Mutex library

Tags: node.js, express, mutex

I have nodejs app - version 10 and i installed Mutex library

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-mutex
```

Following their instructions on npmjs i installed the npm package and tried to require

```
npm i async-mutex
var Mutex = require('async-mutex').Mutex;
```

after that when i start with their example:

```
mutex
    .acquire()
    .then(function(release) {
        // ...
    });
```

i get

```
mutex is not defined ERROR
```

How can i solve this problem ? The npm packages is properly installed and i tried the following:

```
var mutex = require('async-mutex').Mutex
```

then i get mutex.acquire is not a function error

Answer (score 1):

You are missing ONE IMPORTANT part in their documentation:

```
const mutex = new Mutex();
```

So you need to do:

```
var Mutex = require('async-mutex').Mutex;
var mutex = new Mutex();
```

Now you can use `mutex.acquire()`. Note: NOT `Mutex.acquire()`

Comment: Thanks a lot.I just followwed the order on their npmjs. Many thanks !